# select sum of 2 columns to get total value

Tags: sum

I am trying to grab the sum of of 2 columns which are derived by 2 joins in my database. I was expecting my code to yield results but I believe I need to tweak something.

```
SELECT sum(AMT_COST) as COST, SUM(AMT_REV) as REV from cost_info_vw c inner join budget_vw b
on c.bline_bah_id = b.budg_id inner join new_info_vw a
on c.new_info_pid = a.line_id where dept_title = 'Accounting';
```

The current code produces null values for COST and REV. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - I needed to add the syntax c.AMT_COST and c.AMT_REV inside the parentheses.